# Handling data from mobile app to server - realtime or batched csv file or another method?

Tags: rest

I'm working with a 3rd party mobile app that has two methods of transmitting data...

1. Realtime via POST request - each POST request is a row of data per second.  This will be for maybe 5 minutes at each execution of the app.
2. CSV file

I was able to set up a php file to get the data from the POST request and kind of prefer this method but not sure if it's a good idea. I have to store the data in a database (I think Amazon Dynamo) and I don't really need the data to be realtime. Eventually want to build an app that handles the data transfer in a more preferred way and for my specific use case but still don't know what the ideal way is.

**POST**

If I'm capturing the data (doesn't need to be php / probably will write something in Javascript/Nodejs)...

1. Will it be an issue that the inserts are occurring at every POST request?

I would think that a connection to the database is needed for each POST request so it may slow things down.

2. Can there be any issues when there are multiple users around the same time sending data when they are using the app?

Each user can be identified by their device ID so the data correctness shouldn't be an issue and concurrency should be ok on the database

**CSV**

The other option is a CSV file which is fine for now but sending the file is manual. Would want the user to be hands off in terms of sending the data. Does that mean then the only option would be to use POST?

Comment: Which way most effectively meets your specific requirements?

Comment: I want the user to be hands off in having to send the data so I'd imagine the POST route but not sure if that is efficient / a good way based on what I've mentioned. And don't know if there are better ways of handling the data transfer. Most I've ever dealt with are JSON requests that are not in realtime

Comment: The time of 5 Minutes per execution is not good for an OLTP. Why does POST take all this time? Consider FTP.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` will be slow. For a realtime, you'd better to use [a websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

`GET` is a little bit faster than `POST`. You may consider to use get for small amount of data and especially for lots of small requests.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521727/is-get-method-is-faster-than-post

Database most likely be a bottleneck in that scenario. It's possible to partition users by `UserID` or `DeviceID` to reduce database load.

Or you may consider to save data in fast memory based queue and save it to database a little bit later. In this case, it wouldn't be a true realtime application but you could survive higher traffic.

Comment: I suppose GET and POST are equally fast / slow. With POST, you can send a larger batch, though.

Answer (score 0):

REST is not intended for real-time. It can be made fast enough to handle real-time requirements, even with all the HTTP overhead, especially if you can afford `connection: keep`.

Batching and making fewer requests is always easier, if your problem affords it. Sending a CSV file using a POST HTTP request is trivial, it can be a proper REST endpoint if you care about it. Using gzip compression in transfer helps, too.

Inserting into an SQL database in batches is faster in general. For a serious real-time load, you likely need a non-relational DB, like a KV store (Redis, etc), as is, or as a queue in front of an RDBMS.

If you *do* need real-time, websockets are the way to go.

For multiple users, you need at least make the data from different users recognizable. It maybe inside the data, in HTTP headers (as a cookie or as an explicitly set header), or the connection's identity for the websocket. Yes, you do have to come up with a way to do that if you need that. Parallel uploads are going to work just fine, though.